# Python Faster File Writing and Compressing

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
with gzip.open(sys.argv[1] + ".json.gz", mode="w") as outfile:
    s = json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
    print "JSON.DUMP", round(time.time() - start_time_2), "s"
    s = s.encode('utf-8')
    print "Encode.utf8", round(time.time() - start_time_2), "s"
    outfile.write(s)
```

Parsing file done  32.0 s
JSON.DUMP 64.0 s
Encode.utf8 83.0 s
Writing 600s

`s` is about 800Mb big.

After writing the file is 100Mb compressed.
Is there a way to make the writing + compression faster, because it is the bottleneck.

Comment: What are you writing to? I'm not saying that maybe there isn't some stuff, algorithmically, that you could play with, but that a better picture of the hardware/networks you are working with might be (at least) an equally valid place to look for optimizations.

Comment: I am writing to a SSD of a MacBookPro.

Comment: I wonder if the line `s = s.encode('utf-8')` is necessary. The `json.dump` function has a parameter `encoding` which is set to `utf-8` by default.

Comment: yes but this was added in Python 3.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `json.dumps` rather than `json.dump`? Also, if size is an issue are you sure you absolutely need to have the json string indented (adding a storage overhead).

Comment: the encoding parameter is not available in python 2.7. I just dump it to a string to separately encode the string before writing. I don't know if this can be improved.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html section 18.2.1: I can clearly see the `encoding` parameter there.

Comment: yes you are right, it was gzip who doesn't have this feature. But json encoding returns the wrong result.     json.dump(fdata, outfile, indent=2, encoding="utf-8") returns for ü \u00 but i want ü and putting back ensure_ascii = False) returns an error since it can decode it which is strange.